# Linking two value in different custom directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So i have two custom directives as follows:

```
 .directive('myDirective', function(){
   //restrict, template, replace etc.
   scope:{
      myValue:"="
   },
   controller:function(){
    //manipulate myValue
   }
 })
```

and:

```
  .directive('myDirective2', function(){
   //restrict, template, replace etc.
   scope:{
      myValue2: myValue
   },
   controller:function(){
    //prepare myValue2
   }
 })
```

My intention is to link myValue and myValue2 such that when myValue changes, myValue2 also responds.

My custom elements look as follows:

```
 <my-directive ng-repeat='item in array' my-value=item></my-directive>

 <my-directive-2></my-directive-2>
```

Comment: just pass the same variable into each directive in the html. Also `myValue2: (myValue*10)` is not valid. You could write a getter function that multiplies the base value by 10 though

Comment: In-light of my updates, if i add array to my-directive-2 as follows <my-directive-2 myArray="array">, will a change in any instance of item in my-directive affect everything attached to myArray in my-directive-2  @rob

Comment: your syntax for renaming myValue to myValue2 is still not quite valid. Here is a blog post that covers it http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-2-isolated-scope/ . But yes if you pass the same object into both directives then changing it in one directive will update the other one.